# Where is Eclipse getting this mysterious proxy config?

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I'm attempting to using eclipse without a proxy, but it keeps picking up some proxy settings, and I've no idea how:

> Failure to transfer my.stuff:integration.merge:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from http://jcenter.bintray.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jcenter has elapsed or updates are forced. 
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact my.stuff:integration.merge:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from/to jcenter (http://jcenter.bintray.com): www-proxy.mycompany.com

The build works fine when running from maven at the command line:

```
mvn -U clean install
....
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

eclipse network config file

```
Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.core.net.prefs

eclipse.preferences.version=1
nonProxiedHosts=repo.maven.apache.org|localhost|127.0.0.1
org.eclipse.core.net.hasMigrated=true
proxiesEnabled=false
systemProxiesEnabled=false
```

No eclipse config files contain the proxy info:

```
find ~/eclipse/ -type f |xargs grep www-proxy
[nothing returned]
```

Mac System network settings:

[image]

Eclipse proxy settings:

[image: eclipse proxy settings]

`~/.bash_profile` contains no references to the proxy either.

And I've got no `~/.m2/settings.xml` file - so it's not being taken from there.

Question: where is eclipse getting this proxy info from?  And why is using it, when it's been explicitly configured not to do so?

Comment: See http://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/set-proxy-for-maven-in-eclipse.html

Comment: @howlger that shows me how to _enable_ proxy use.  I'm trying to _disable_ it.  But I did forget to mention in the question that I have no settings.xml file - now corrected.